# how to set web socket client unmasked mode text frame in netty4

Tags: websocket, netty

How  to set web socket client unmasked mode in  text frame in netty4?

Now I am use the websocket client in  netty4 to send websocket request, now I want search the text sent in tcpdump file  or Wireshark file .Now the text is masked and I could not search it with original text in tcpdump file or Wireshark  file.

Comment: It must be masked as otherwise it is not conform to the RFC

Answer (score 1):

While [RFC-6455, Section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3) states that a Masking Key is required for Client to Server communications.  It is possible to have the masking key be all zeros (albeit against the other recommendations in the same RFC that a client must pick a fresh masking key for each frame)

But that being said, Wireshark 1.10+ is capable of dissecting masked websocket frames easily enough, making the searching for text message payload content trivial.